# How to prevent clip thread from terminating?

Tags: java, audio

My program doesn't get to play any audio before it's terminated. I've heard it's due to its thread being terminated, so I am wondering if there is a way I can keep the thread running so that the audio can be played?

```
public class Music {
    void playMusic(String musicLocation) {
        try {
            File musicPath = new File(musicLocation);
            if (musicPath.exists()) {
                AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInput);
                clip.start();
                clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Can't find file.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont fully understand, you want to play audio after you terminate your program? Or maybe your audio stops when some other operations are running? Did you consider using another thread to play music?

Answer (score 0):

First, a little background info about threads. The following is from the API Specification, for the [Thread class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html).

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single
> non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some
> designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute
> threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception
>   that propagates beyond the run method.

The thread created that is launched when running a `Clip` is a daemon thread. And so, it will not qualify to keep the JVM open for processing. The logical solution would be to obtain a reference to the thread and call the [setDaemon()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)) method to make it a user thread. But I am not aware of any way to get a reference to the thread.

The alternative is to ensure a user thread is active for the duration of the playback. It's pretty common in tutorials to do this by adding a [Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) command to the user thread that launches the sound, specifying the length of time needed for the user thread to stay suspended while the sound is playing. This is very quick and easy to code. But it is rare to use this in a regular application. One doesn't normally want the CPU to suspend processing while waiting for the sound to complete.

Much more common in applications, a GUI of some sort is involved. GUI's make use of user threads, and will hold the JVM open until the GUI is closed. So, as long as the GUI is open, sounds will run. To test this, perhaps make a simple GUI holding a button control, and have the button launch the sound. As long as the GUI remains open, the sound should have time to complete.

Another common situation is the have another user thread running as a separate process, e.g., a multi-threaded application. As long as a user thread is running, daemon threads will also continue.